# autoSizeStrategy in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to use the autoSizeStrategy option in ag-grid.  From reading the docs, it seems it should autosize the grid columns based on the strategy selected when the data is loaded.  I'm using a client side model, where all data is passed in with rowData into the options.   Adding this option seems to do nothing, however.

I'm using typescript/react with AG-Grid.  I'm either mis-understanding what this should do, or doing something wrong. I want the grid to re-size columns when data is loaded such that the columns size to the contents of the cells.

````
'''
[...]  

const autoSizeStrategy = {
    type: 'fitCellContents'
};

[...]

          <AgGridReact
          autoSizeStrategy={autoSizeStrategy}
          rowDragManaged={true}
          onGridReady={onGridReady}
          gridOptions={gridOptions}
          onCellValueChanged={onCellValueChanged}
          onRowClicked={handleRowClick}
          rowData={localQueryData}
          columnDefs={localColumns}
          suppressColumnVirtualisation={true}
          rowDragEntireRow={true}
          rowDragText={rowDragText}
          onRowDragEnter={onRowDragEnter}
          onRowDragEnd={onRowDragEnd} />
```
````

I have a button tied to the following function which does work correctly

````
```
function autoSize() {
  if (gridApiRef.current) {
    gridApiRef.current.autoSizeAllColumns();
  }
 }
```
````